# Laptop external monitor no longer being detected

Tags: windows-8, laptop, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, hdmi

I have an HP ENVY TouchSmart 4-1215dx Ultrabook Laptop running Windows 8.1. All hardware is standard except I upgraded the 4GB of RAM to 8GB. Up until recently (2-3 days ago), I have had no issues connecting my laptop to external monitors via HDMI (no VGA).

Now, however, every time I connect anything to my HDMI port it simply does nothing. It doesn't detect or show the additional display when in `Right-click Desktop > Screen Resolution`. Also, when my monitor is just sitting without any input, it says `No DVI-D Cable. The display will go into Power Save Mode in 5 minutes.` When I plug in my laptop, the monitor immediately goes to sleep.

I don't know of an event that would have caused a change in functionality. The only thing that seemed to somewhat coincide with this is my OS recently (yesterday) got removed from the BCD and I had to rebuild the BCD from the system recovery command line tool in order to get it to boot.

I have tried rebooting, reconnecting the monitor, and plugging in the monitor before I start up my laptop. I also tried re-installing the Video Driver using the HP-provided drivers [here](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=4158&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=5360163)

Any ideas where else to look or what else to do? I have looked around and haven't been able to find any leads. My only thought is that it's a hardware problem and I somehow messed up my HDMI port. Thoughts?

Comment: Its possible you had hardware fail on you, but if that happen, its unlikely you did anything to make it fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard battery of tests to isolate the issue, in order:

1) Use a known good HDMI cable to connect the monitor to your laptop.  If it works, your cable is the problem.

2) Use a known good HDMI cable to connect the monitor to another device.  If it works, your laptop is the problem.

3) Use a known good HDMI cable to connect another known good monitor to your laptop.  If it work, your monitor is the issue.

1 Is easy and cheap.  3 is easy and expensive (try connecting via another port on the monitor, DVI or something - might be the HDMI port on the monitor).  2 is the hard one - could be the HDMI port (try other ports) or could be the software.

I suspect it's the laptop.  Try installing the manufacturer's drivers rather than the ones from HP, if that's possible.

Comment: Well it's definitely my laptop then. The monitor's I've plugged in for sure work, and the HDMI cables are good because they work in other computers. I wish I had a VGA port, but I don't. Maybe I'll have to break down and buy a VGA to HDMI converter. Even if it is super expensive. Where would I be able to find the manufacturer's drivers? Or, for that matter, even the manufacturer of my laptop? I thought it was HP... On that note, however, I was probably going to reimage my laptop after this semester is over. I wonder if that would fix it?

Comment: You'd want the drivers for the manufacturer of the video card, not the laptop as a whole.  Check Device Manager if this is Windows for the name and manufacturer of the video card and go from there - maybe you're lucky and it's software, not hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.I have a sony vaio laptop. I had a TV connected using HDMI, it used to work fine, but one day it did not. The VGA cable still worked fine.

Here is the solution: Reboot PC. Go to bios, by pressing F2 or which ever key is correct for your computer. In the Bios setting, Disable Intel Visualization technology. Reboot computer. And it should work. If there is no such option, go to bios and restore original bios setting from the bios menu.